# Cannot retrieve a VB.ListBox object passed from a VB6 EXE to a VB6 DLL when debugging DLL

Tags: dll, com, listbox, vb6

I'm maintaining a DLL with logging feature. I wanted to add a ListBox parameter to a method of this DLL to allow on display logging.

Basically this dll could be described this way :

```
' Class loggingDll.loggingObject
Public Function processIt([...], aLogBox As Object)
' Simple test code lines...
Dim l As VB.ListBox
Set l = aLogBox
' [...]
End Function
```

The EXE comes with a GUI, a VB.ListBox included. This `ListBox` (let's call it `LogBox`) is passed to the DLL in a way looking like this :

```
' Exe DllCaller.Exe
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim aLoggingObject as loggingDll.loggingObject
    Set aLoggingObject = New loggingDll.loggingObject
    aLoggingObject.processIt(LogBox)
End Sub
```

This works perfectly fine when I run the EXE. But when running the DLL in debug mode whith this EXE (Project->Properties->Debugging tab option "Start program" with the path to the EXE), I get an ugly "Type Mismatch" at `Set l = aLogBox`.

I added a spy on the `aLogBox` variable. `TypeName(aLogBox)` returns `"ListBox"`, but the content of `aLogBox` is empty (although a `VB.ListBox` object is full of properties).

What's happening ? Why debug mode has not the same behaviour ?

Comment: Why not pass `aLogBox As VB.ListBox` ?

Comment: If I do such thing in the prototype of the function `processIt()` in the DLL source, I get : `"Compile error : Private object modules cannot be used in public object modules as parameters or return types for public procedures, as public data members, or as fields of public user defined types"`